# sendOobCode Google Identity Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-identity, google-identity-toolkit

I'm trying to use Google Identity platform api's with my firebase project ( I configured a payment method to use the identity platform [sendOobCode](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/sendOobCode) and [sendVerificationCode](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/sendVerificationCode) methods. But I keep receiving a 400 ERROR.

I tried using the built-in api calls in the console and got back more detailed errors.

```
"errors": [ { "message": "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND", "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid" } ] }


createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                                    .then((userCredential) => {
                                        var url = 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=[]';
                                        var data = {
                                            // requestType: "VERIFY_EMAIL",
                                            idToken: userCredential._tokenResponse.idToken
                                        }
                                        console.log(userCredential)
                                        axios.post(url, data, {
                                            headers: {
                                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                            }
                                        }).then((res) => {
                                            console.log(res)
                                        }).catch((err) => {
                                            console.log(err)
                                        })
    
                                    })
                                    .catch((error) => {
    .....
    })
```

Comment: Are you trying to verify oobCode? Also can you share your API request?

Comment: I figured it out but is there a way to send a code to a user's email to verify ?

Comment: Why not use the Firebase SDK directly to send verification email? `await sendEmailVerification(userCredential.user)`

Comment: I didn't realize they are the same. I want to send a code instead of a verification link. How can I make that possible?

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to get more information on my error by going into the `Network` Section in the dev tools. I checked the 400 request error and found in the response that I have an invalid API key. I forgot to remove the [] :)

Comment: just adding extra clarification because I missed this: the error message can be found in the Network tab, specifically in the Response sub-tab